# Limitar el tiempo de ejecución de un archivo - PHP

Tags: php, apache

Estoy diseñando un contandor que me envía un registro a una base de datos cada vez de que una `url` en `php` sea ejecutada, el problema que tengo es que si esta `url` se carga desde una pantalla en un servidor en especifico, a veces estos servidores generan 3 lecturas o más en un mismo microsegundo.

El código lo tengo diseñado con una validación de que si existe un registro en la base de datos con determinados valores no registre otro, pero la ejecución de la `URL` es tan rápida que las lecturas o aperturas de `URL` pasan por esa validación las 3 al mismo tiempo, por lo tanto no puedo validarlo con una consulta a la base de datos.

Mi pregunta es si existe la manera de limitar el tiempo de ejecución de un `script` cada tantos milisegundos, es decir que un intervalo de tiempo dicho `script` no pueda ejecutarse.

Comment: agrega el código que tienes... ya conoces las reglas del sitio!

Comment: El codigo que tengo es indiferente y en nada ayuda a resolver mi problema. una Select cualqiuera a una tabla para validar si existe el registro y si no existe ingrese otro, validación que se salta por las razones que ya describí.

Comment: Hola Luis, no entiendo para qué quieres agregar latencia a la aplicación?, necesitas saber cuánto tarda en ser atendida cada petición?, o necesitas encolar escrituras en la base de datos?

Comment: Algunos servidores de correo dan respuesta triple cuando envías una url de lectura en tu correo, no quiero que me genere esa triple lectura, quiero que solo me genere una y las validaciones no me funcionan ya que el tiempo de ejecución de cada electura se da en microsegundos y se salta las validaciones.

Comment: Podrías compartir el código donde pusiste las validaciones que no funcionan?

Comment: Por que no buscas los índices apropiados en base de datos para hacer un unique y que no se puedan duplicar?

Answer (score 3):

según logré entender, lo que te puede servir es usar un semáforo:

```
<?php

define('SEM_KEY', 1000);

function el_metodo_sincrono() {
    $semRes = sem_get(SEM_KEY, 1, 0666, 0);

    if(sem_acquire($semRes)) {
        // Aquí va el código que quieres ejecutar
        sem_release($semRes); // Al finalizar liberas el semáforo
    }
}
```

Para más información lee: http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función,

```
set_time_limit ( $seconds )
```

Esta función limita el tiempo de ejecución de un script. Lo que hace es prácticamente matar la aplicación cuando se supera el tiempo limite de ejecución.
Sin embargo, por lo que entiendo es que quieres que cada ejecución se haga secuencial, por lo que podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
public function validar(){
$this->validacion1();
$this->validacion2();
$this->validacion3();
}
public function validacion1(){
//Codigo
}
public function validacion2(){
//Codigo
}
public function validacion3(){
//Codigo
}
```

Comment: No es lo que estoy buscando, esa funcion busca medir un tiempo minimo de respuesta de no cumplirse en ese tiempo arroja un error, lo que yo estoy buscando es totalmente lo contrario